# reset_password_token getting zapped out of url on validation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

**I need devise to pass back the reset_password_token to the view on validation errors**.
Now, if the validation fails it goes to:  `/customers/password` which looses the `?reset_password_token=foobar`

*This is from my model:*

```
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :validatable,
         :rememberable, :trackable, :authentication_keys => [:email, :storefront_id],
         :reset_password_keys => [:email, :storefront_id]
```

*This is from the form action in the view:*

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => password_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :post }) do |f| %>
```

*These are the routes:*

```
customer_password      POST   /:subdomain/customers/password(.:format)      customer_passwords#create
new_customer_password  GET    /:subdomain/customers/password/new(.:format)  customer_passwords#new
edit_customer_password GET    /:subdomain/customers/password/edit(.:format) customer_passwords#edit 
                       PUT    /:subdomain/customers/password(.:format)      customer_passwords#update
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because form submit does a [POST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) request and all attributes are passed in a request message body.

And :reset_password_token is stored in a hidden field when you submit a form. https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/views/devise/passwords/edit.html.erb